# conflicting jquery effecting my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

The site is [VelocityMicro.com](http://www.velocitymicro.com). I know I tried posting earlier today but but I accidentally hit "submit" before I remembered to put the code in.  SO if this is the second time you're seeing this question, I promise I'll be more specific.

My main issue is that the dropdown menu works on every page except three.
[Cruz.php](http://www.velocitymicro.com) /PC.php /velocityHPC.php

The only thing that makes these pages different from the rest of the site is that they're product category pages and halfway down the page, there are category breakdown tabs.

My concern is that there is an overlap somewhere in the coding I have to make those category breakdown tabs work that is keeping the drop down menu from working.

**JQUERY.JCAROUSEL.JS**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.jcarousel = function(o) {
    if (typeof o == 'string') {
        var instance = $(this).data('jcarousel'), args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return instance[o].apply(instance, args);
    } else
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).data('jcarousel', new $jc(this, o));
        });
};

// Default configuration properties.
var defaults = {
    vertical: false,
    rtl: false,
    start: 1,
    offset: 1,
    size: null,
    scroll: 3,
    visible: null,
    animation: 'normal',
    easing: 'swing',
    auto: 0,
    wrap: null,
    initCallback: null,
    reloadCallback: null,
    itemLoadCallback: null,
    itemFirstInCallback: null,
    itemFirstOutCallback: null,
    itemLastInCallback: null,
    itemLastOutCallback: null,
    itemVisibleInCallback: null,
    itemVisibleOutCallback: null,
    buttonNextHTML: '<div></div>',
    buttonPrevHTML: '<div></div>',
    buttonNextEvent: 'click',
    buttonPrevEvent: 'click',
    buttonNextCallback: null,
    buttonPrevCallback: null,
    itemFallbackDimension: null
}, windowLoaded = false;

$(window).bind('load.jcarousel', function() { windowLoaded = true; })


$.jcarousel = function(e, o) {
    this.options    = $.extend({}, defaults, o || {});

    this.locked     = false;

    this.container  = null;
    this.clip       = null;
    this.list       = null;
    this.buttonNext = null;
    this.buttonPrev = null;


    if (!o || o.rtl === undefined)
        this.options.rtl = ($(e).attr('dir') || $('html').attr('dir') || '').toLowerCase() == 'rtl';

    this.wh = !this.options.vertical ? 'width' : 'height';
    this.lt = !this.options.vertical ? (this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left') : 'top';


    var skin = '', split = e.className.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i].indexOf('jcarousel-skin') != -1) {
            $(e).removeClass(split[i]);
            skin = split[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (e.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'UL' || e.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'OL') {
        this.list = $(e);
        this.container = this.list.parent();

        if (this.container.hasClass('jcarousel-clip')) {
            if (!this.container.parent().hasClass('jcarousel-container'))
                this.container = this.container.wrap('<div></div>');

            this.container = this.container.parent();
        } else if (!this.container.hasClass('jcarousel-container'))
            this.container = this.list.wrap('<div></div>').parent();
    } else {
        this.container = $(e);
        this.list = this.container.find('ul,ol').eq(0);
    }

    if (skin != '' && this.container.parent()[0].className.indexOf('jcarousel-skin') == -1)
        this.container.wrap('<div class=" '+ skin + '"></div>');

    this.clip = this.list.parent();

    if (!this.clip.length || !this.clip.hasClass('jcarousel-clip'))
        this.clip = this.list.wrap('<div></div>').parent();

    this.buttonNext = $('.jcarousel-next', this.container);

    if (this.buttonNext.size() == 0 && this.options.buttonNextHTML != null)
        this.buttonNext = this.clip.after(this.options.buttonNextHTML).next();

    this.buttonNext.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-next'));

    this.buttonPrev = $('.jcarousel-prev', this.container);

    if (this.buttonPrev.size() == 0 && this.options.buttonPrevHTML != null)
        this.buttonPrev = this.clip.after(this.options.buttonPrevHTML).next();

    this.buttonPrev.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-prev'));

    this.clip.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-clip')).css({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative'
    });
    this.list.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-list')).css({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        position: 'relative',
        top: 0,
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0
    }).css((this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'), 0);
    this.container.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-container')).css({
        position: 'relative'
    });
    if (!this.options.vertical && this.options.rtl)
        this.container.addClass('jcarousel-direction-rtl').attr('dir', 'rtl');

    var di = this.options.visible != null ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null;
    var li = this.list.children('li');

    var self = this;

    if (li.size() > 0) {
        var wh = 0, i = this.options.offset;
        li.each(function() {
            self.format(this, i++);
            wh += self.dimension(this, di);
        });

        this.list.css(this.wh, (wh + 100) + 'px');


        if (!o || o.size === undefined)
            this.options.size = li.size();
    }

    // For whatever reason, .show() does not work in Safari...
    this.container.css('display', 'block');
    this.buttonNext.css('display', 'block');
    this.buttonPrev.css('display', 'block');

    this.funcNext   = function() { self.next(); };
    this.funcPrev   = function() { self.prev(); };
    this.funcResize = function() { self.reload(); };

    if (this.options.initCallback != null)
        this.options.initCallback(this, 'init');

    if (!windowLoaded && $.browser.safari) {
        this.buttons(false, false);
        $(window).bind('load.jcarousel', function() { self.setup(); });
    } else
        this.setup();
};


var $jc = $.jcarousel;

$jc.fn = $jc.prototype = {
    jcarousel: '0.2.5'
};

$jc.fn.extend = $jc.extend = $.extend;

$jc.fn.extend({

    setup: function() {
        this.first     = null;
        this.last      = null;
        this.prevFirst = null;
        this.prevLast  = null;
        this.animating = false;
        this.timer     = null;
        this.tail      = null;
        this.inTail    = false;

        if (this.locked)
            return;

        this.list.css(this.lt, this.pos(this.options.offset) + 'px');
        var p = this.pos(this.options.start);
        this.prevFirst = this.prevLast = null;
        this.animate(p, false);

        $(window).unbind('resize.jcarousel', this.funcResize).bind('resize.jcarousel', this.funcResize);
    },


    reset: function() {
        this.list.empty();

        this.list.css(this.lt, '0px');
        this.list.css(this.wh, '10px');

        if (this.options.initCallback != null)
            this.options.initCallback(this, 'reset');

        this.setup();
    },

    reload: function() {
        if (this.tail != null && this.inTail)
            this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + this.tail);

        this.tail   = null;
        this.inTail = false;

        if (this.options.reloadCallback != null)
            this.options.reloadCallback(this);

        if (this.options.visible != null) {
            var self = this;
            var di = Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible), wh = 0, lt = 0;
            this.list.children('li').each(function(i) {
                wh += self.dimension(this, di);
                if (i + 1 < self.first)
                    lt = wh;
            });

            this.list.css(this.wh, wh + 'px');
            this.list.css(this.lt, -lt + 'px');
        }

        this.scroll(this.first, false);
    },


    lock: function() {
        this.locked = true;
        this.buttons();
    },

    unlock: function() {
        this.locked = false;
        this.buttons();
    },

    size: function(s) {
        if (s != undefined) {
            this.options.size = s;
            if (!this.locked)
                this.buttons();
        }

        return this.options.size;
    },

    has: function(i, i2) {
        if (i2 == undefined || !i2)
            i2 = i;

        if (this.options.size !== null && i2 > this.options.size)
            i2 = this.options.size;

        for (var j = i; j <= i2; j++) {
            var e = this.get(j);
            if (!e.length || e.hasClass('jcarousel-item-placeholder'))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    },

    get: function(i) {
        return $('.jcarousel-item-' + i, this.list);
    },

    add: function(i, s) {
        var e = this.get(i), old = 0, n = $(s);

        if (e.length == 0) {
            var c, e = this.create(i), j = $jc.intval(i);
            while (c = this.get(--j)) {
                if (j <= 0 || c.length) {
                    j <= 0 ? this.list.prepend(e) : c.after(e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
            old = this.dimension(e);

        if (n.get(0).nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
            e.replaceWith(n);
            e = n;
        } else
            e.empty().append(s);

        this.format(e.removeClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder')), i);

        var di = this.options.visible != null ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null;
        var wh = this.dimension(e, di) - old;

        if (i > 0 && i < this.first)
            this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) - wh + 'px');

        this.list.css(this.wh, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) + wh + 'px');

        return e;
    },

    remove: function(i) {
        var e = this.get(i);

        // Check if item exists and is not currently visible
        if (!e.length || (i >= this.first && i <= this.last))
            return;

        var d = this.dimension(e);

        if (i < this.first)
            this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + d + 'px');

        e.remove();

        this.list.css(this.wh, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) - d + 'px');
    },

    next: function() {
        this.stopAuto();

        if (this.tail != null && !this.inTail)
            this.scrollTail(false);
        else
            this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'last') && this.options.size != null && this.last == this.options.size) ? 1 : this.first + this.options.scroll);
    },

    prev: function() {
        this.stopAuto();

        if (this.tail != null && this.inTail)
            this.scrollTail(true);
        else
            this.scroll(((this.options.wrap == 'both' || this.options.wrap == 'first') && this.options.size != null && this.first == 1) ? this.options.size : this.first - this.options.scroll);
    },

    scrollTail: function(b) {
        if (this.locked || this.animating || !this.tail)
            return;

        var pos  = $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt));

        !b ? pos -= this.tail : pos += this.tail;
        this.inTail = !b;

        this.prevFirst = this.first;
        this.prevLast  = this.last;

        this.animate(pos);
    },

    scroll: function(i, a) {
        if (this.locked || this.animating)
            return;

        this.animate(this.pos(i), a);
    },

    pos: function(i) {
        var pos  = $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt));

        if (this.locked || this.animating)
            return pos;

        if (this.options.wrap != 'circular')
            i = i < 1 ? 1 : (this.options.size && i > this.options.size ? this.options.size : i);

        var back = this.first > i;


        var f = this.options.wrap != 'circular' && this.first <= 1 ? 1 : this.first;
        var c = back ? this.get(f) : this.get(this.last);
        var j = back ? f : f - 1;
        var e = null, l = 0, p = false, d = 0, g;

        while (back ? --j >= i : ++j < i) {
            e = this.get(j);
            p = !e.length;
            if (e.length == 0) {
                e = this.create(j).addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder'));
                c[back ? 'before' : 'after' ](e);

                if (this.first != null && this.options.wrap == 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && (j <= 0 || j > this.options.size)) {
                    g = this.get(this.index(j));
                    if (g.length)
                        e = this.add(j, g.clone(true));
                }
            }

            c = e;
            d = this.dimension(e);

            if (p)
                l += d;

            if (this.first != null && (this.options.wrap == 'circular' || (j >= 1 && (this.options.size == null || j <= this.options.size))))
                pos = back ? pos + d : pos - d;
        }


        var clipping = this.clipping();
        var cache = [];
        var visible = 0, j = i, v = 0;
        var c = this.get(i - 1);

        while (++visible) {
            e = this.get(j);
            p = !e.length;
            if (e.length == 0) {
                e = this.create(j).addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-placeholder'));

                c.length == 0 ? this.list.prepend(e) : c[back ? 'before' : 'after' ](e);

                if (this.first != null && this.options.wrap == 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && (j <= 0 || j > this.options.size)) {
                    g = this.get(this.index(j));
                    if (g.length)
                        e = this.add(j, g.clone(true));
                }
            }

            c = e;
            var d = this.dimension(e);
            if (d == 0) {
                throw new Error('jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...');
            }

            if (this.options.wrap != 'circular' && this.options.size !== null && j > this.options.size)
                cache.push(e);
            else if (p)
                l += d;

            v += d;

            if (v >= clipping)
                break;

            j++;
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < cache.length; x++)
            cache[x].remove();

        if (l > 0) {
            this.list.css(this.wh, this.dimension(this.list) + l + 'px');

            if (back) {
                pos -= l;
                this.list.css(this.lt, $jc.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) - l + 'px');
            }
        }

        var last = i + visible - 1;
        if (this.options.wrap != 'circular' && this.options.size && last > this.options.size)
            last = this.options.size;

        if (j > last) {
            visible = 0, j = last, v = 0;
            while (++visible) {
                var e = this.get(j--);
                if (!e.length)
                    break;
                v += this.dimension(e);
                if (v >= clipping)
                    break;
            }
        }

        var first = last - visible + 1;
        if (this.options.wrap != 'circular' && first < 1)
            first = 1;

        if (this.inTail && back) {
            pos += this.tail;
            this.inTail = false;
        }

        this.tail = null;
        if (this.options.wrap != 'circular' && last == this.options.size && (last - visible + 1) >= 1) {
            var m = $jc.margin(this.get(last), !this.options.vertical ? 'marginRight' : 'marginBottom');
            if ((v - m) > clipping)
                this.tail = v - clipping - m;
        }

        // Adjust position
        while (i-- > first)
            pos += this.dimension(this.get(i));

        // Save visible item range
        this.prevFirst = this.first;
        this.prevLast  = this.last;
        this.first     = first;
        this.last      = last;

        return pos;
    },

    animate: function(p, a) {
        if (this.locked || this.animating)
            return;

        this.animating = true;

        var self = this;
        var scrolled = function() {
            self.animating = false;

            if (p == 0)
                self.list.css(self.lt,  0);

            if (self.options.wrap == 'circular' || self.options.wrap == 'both' || self.options.wrap == 'last' || self.options.size == null || self.last < self.options.size)
                self.startAuto();

            self.buttons();
            self.notify('onAfterAnimation');


            if (self.options.wrap == 'circular' && self.options.size !== null)
                for (var i = self.prevFirst; i <= self.prevLast; i++)
                    if (i !== null && !(i >= self.first && i <= self.last) && (i < 1 || i > self.options.size))
                        self.remove(i);
        };

        this.notify('onBeforeAnimation');

        // Animate
        if (!this.options.animation || a == false) {
            this.list.css(this.lt, p + 'px');
            scrolled();
        } else {
            var o = !this.options.vertical ? (this.options.rtl ? {'right': p} : {'left': p}) : {'top': p};
            this.list.animate(o, this.options.animation, this.options.easing, scrolled);
        }
    },

    startAuto: function(s) {
        if (s != undefined)
            this.options.auto = s;

        if (this.options.auto == 0)
            return this.stopAuto();

        if (this.timer != null)
            return;

        var self = this;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function() { self.next(); }, this.options.auto * 2000);
    },

    stopAuto: function() {
        if (this.timer == null)
            return;

        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = null;
    },

    buttons: function(n, p) {
        if (n == undefined || n == null) {
            var n = !this.locked && this.options.size !== 0 && ((this.options.wrap && this.options.wrap != 'first') || this.options.size == null || this.last < this.options.size);
            if (!this.locked && (!this.options.wrap || this.options.wrap == 'first') && this.options.size != null && this.last >= this.options.size)
                n = this.tail != null && !this.inTail;
        }

        if (p == undefined || p == null) {
            var p = !this.locked && this.options.size !== 0 && ((this.options.wrap && this.options.wrap != 'last') || this.first > 1);
            if (!this.locked && (!this.options.wrap || this.options.wrap == 'last') && this.options.size != null && this.first == 1)
                p = this.tail != null && this.inTail;
        }

        var self = this;

        this.buttonNext[n ? 'bind' : 'unbind'](this.options.buttonNextEvent + '.jcarousel', this.funcNext)[n ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](this.className('jcarousel-next-disabled')).attr('disabled', n ? false : true);
        this.buttonPrev[p ? 'bind' : 'unbind'](this.options.buttonPrevEvent + '.jcarousel', this.funcPrev)[p ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](this.className('jcarousel-prev-disabled')).attr('disabled', p ? false : true);

        if (this.options.buttonNextCallback != null && this.buttonNext.data('jcarouselstate') != n) {
            this.buttonNext.each(function() { self.options.buttonNextCallback(self, this, n); }).data('jcarouselstate', n);
        }

        if (this.options.buttonPrevCallback != null && (this.buttonPrev.data('jcarouselstate') != p)) {
            this.buttonPrev.each(function() { self.options.buttonPrevCallback(self, this, p); }).data('jcarouselstate', p);
        }
    },

    notify: function(evt) {
        var state = this.prevFirst == null ? 'init' : (this.prevFirst < this.first ? 'next' : 'prev');

        // Load items
        this.callback('itemLoadCallback', evt, state);

        if (this.prevFirst !== this.first) {
            this.callback('itemFirstInCallback', evt, state, this.first);
            this.callback('itemFirstOutCallback', evt, state, this.prevFirst);
        }

        if (this.prevLast !== this.last) {
            this.callback('itemLastInCallback', evt, state, this.last);
            this.callback('itemLastOutCallback', evt, state, this.prevLast);
        }

        this.callback('itemVisibleInCallback', evt, state, this.first, this.last, this.prevFirst, this.prevLast);
        this.callback('itemVisibleOutCallback', evt, state, this.prevFirst, this.prevLast, this.first, this.last);
    },

    callback: function(cb, evt, state, i1, i2, i3, i4) {
        if (this.options[cb] == undefined || (typeof this.options[cb] != 'object' && evt != 'onAfterAnimation'))
            return;

        var callback = typeof this.options[cb] == 'object' ? this.options[cb][evt] : this.options[cb];

        if (!$.isFunction(callback))
            return;

        var self = this;

        if (i1 === undefined)
            callback(self, state, evt);
        else if (i2 === undefined)
            this.get(i1).each(function() { callback(self, this, i1, state, evt); });
        else {
            for (var i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
                if (i !== null && !(i >= i3 && i <= i4))
                    this.get(i).each(function() { callback(self, this, i, state, evt); });
        }
    },

    create: function(i) {
        return this.format('<li></li>', i);
    },

    format: function(e, i) {
        var e = $(e), split = e.get(0).className.split(' ');
        for (var j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
            if (split[j].indexOf('jcarousel-') != -1) {
                e.removeClass(split[j]);
            }
        }
        e.addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item')).addClass(this.className('jcarousel-item-' + i)).css({
            'float': (this.options.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'),
            'list-style': 'none'
        }).attr('jcarouselindex', i);
        return e;
    },

    className: function(c) {
        return c + ' ' + c + (!this.options.vertical ? '-horizontal' : '-vertical');
    },

    dimension: function(e, d) {
        var el = e.jquery != undefined ? e[0] : e;

        var old = !this.options.vertical ?
            (el.offsetWidth || $jc.intval(this.options.itemFallbackDimension)) + $jc.margin(el, 'marginLeft') + $jc.margin(el, 'marginRight') :
            (el.offsetHeight || $jc.intval(this.options.itemFallbackDimension)) + $jc.margin(el, 'marginTop') + $jc.margin(el, 'marginBottom');

        if (d == undefined || old == d)
            return old;

        var w = !this.options.vertical ?
            d - $jc.margin(el, 'marginLeft') - $jc.margin(el, 'marginRight') :
            d - $jc.margin(el, 'marginTop') - $jc.margin(el, 'marginBottom');

        $(el).css(this.wh, w + 'px');

        return this.dimension(el);
    },

    clipping: function() {
        return !this.options.vertical ?
            this.clip[0].offsetWidth - $jc.intval(this.clip.css('borderLeftWidth')) - $jc.intval(this.clip.css('borderRightWidth')) :
            this.clip[0].offsetHeight - $jc.intval(this.clip.css('borderTopWidth')) - $jc.intval(this.clip.css('borderBottomWidth'));
    },

    index: function(i, s) {
        if (s == undefined)
            s = this.options.size;

        return Math.round((((i-1) / s) - Math.floor((i-1) / s)) * s) + 1;
    }
});

$jc.extend({
    /**
     * Gets/Sets the global default configuration properties.
     *
     * @method defaults
     * @return {Object}
     * @param d {Object} A set of key/value pairs to set as configuration properties.
     */
    defaults: function(d) {
        return $.extend(defaults, d || {});
    },

    margin: function(e, p) {
        if (!e)
            return 0;

        var el = e.jquery != undefined ? e[0] : e;

        if (p == 'marginRight' && $.browser.safari) {
            var old = {'display': 'block', 'float': 'none', 'width': 'auto'}, oWidth, oWidth2;

            $.swap(el, old, function() { oWidth = el.offsetWidth; });

            old['marginRight'] = 0;
            $.swap(el, old, function() { oWidth2 = el.offsetWidth; });

            return oWidth2 - oWidth;
        }

        return $jc.intval($.css(el, p));
    },

    intval: function(v) {
        v = parseInt(v);
        return isNaN(v) ? 0 : v;
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

**JQUERY.SLIDE.JS**

```
(function($) {

$.fn.slide = function(settings){
    var _link = $(this);
    var _parent = _link.parent();
    var _slide_selector = settings.slide_selector;
    var _auto = settings.auto || false;
    var _time = settings.time || 5000;

    var _index = 0;
    var _max_index = $(this).length;
    var _interval;

    _link.click(function(){
        _index = _link.parent().find('a').index(this);

        if( _auto ) {
            _clear_interval();
            _set_interval();
        }

        _set_index();

        return false;
    });

    function _set_index(){
        _link.removeClass('active');
        _link.eq(_index).addClass('active');


        $(_slide_selector).hide();
        $(_slide_selector).eq(_index).fadeIn();


    }

    function _set_interval() {
        _interval = window.setInterval(_next, _time);
    }

    function _clear_interval(){
        window.clearInterval(_interval);
    }

    function _next(){
        _index++;
        if( _index == _max_index ) {
            _index = 0;
        }

        _set_index();
    }

    _set_index();

    if( _auto ) {
        _set_interval();
    }
}

})(jQuery);
```

**EASYSLIDER1.5.JS**

```
(function($) {
easySlider = function(options){
    var defaults = {
        speed:          10,
        pause:          10,
        continuous:     true
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);        
    var s;
    var w ;       
    var ts;
    var t = 0;

    $(".arrow-right").click(function(){            
        animateClick("next");
        return false;
    });
    $(".arrow-left").click(function(){
        animateClick("prev");
        return false;
    });

    function animateClick(dir){
         var src= $('.project .main-image-holder, .project-item.active .image-holder');
        s = $("li", src).length;
        ts = s-1;
        w = $("li", src).width();

        src.find('li').removeClass('active');

        var ot = t;
        switch(dir){
            case "next":
                t = (ot>=ts) ? (options.continuous ? 0 : ts) : t+1;
                break;
            case "prev":
                t = (t<=0) ? (options.continuous ? ts : 0) : t-1;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        };
        src.find('li').eq(t).addClass('active');
        var diff = Math.abs(ot-t);
        var speed = diff*options.speed;

        if(!options.vertical) {
            p = (t*w*-1);
            src.find("ul").animate(
            {
                marginLeft: p
            },
```

Comment: Is there a Java portion here or just Javascript?

Comment: You're using jQuery 1.4.1 in all the non working pages, while you've got jQuery 1.4.2 on the home. Try replacing the old jQuery version with the new one.

Comment: StepTNT -- I now have 1.4.2 but there doesnt seem to be a change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three pages do not include your `js-func.js`, which is used to initialize your dropdown menu.

I don't know how proficient you are with Javascript; if you just need a quick solution that works, try this:

1. Edit the file `jquery-func.js`
2. Paste the following content in on line 2, just after `$( document ).ready( function(){`:

   ```
   $('#navigation ul li').hover(function(){ 
     $(this).find('a:eq(0)').addClass('hover');
     $(this).find('.dd-holder:eq(0)').show();
   },function(){ 
     $(this).find('a:eq(0)').removeClass('hover');
     $(this).find('.dd-holder:eq(0)').hide();
   });
   ```

   and remove js_func.js from the three pages again.

Comment: @Lorna `js-func.js` stops executing with an error on those pages, because it tries to initialize a slider that isn't there (`Uncaught ReferenceError: easySlider is not defined`).

Comment: ok, there's an easyslider now.  (i know im a total n00b on this.  thanks for being so patient ^_^ )

Comment: Glad if it works. If it doesn't, I just updated my answer with another possible solution for you. If it does solve your problem, I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as correct.